Ticket to Ride Europe: Can owner of Smyrna station claim the routes Palermo to Constantinople?
Can the owner of the Smyrna station claim the routes for the destination ticket Palermo to Constantinople?



A Train Station allows its owner to use one, and only one, of the routes belonging to another player, into (or out of) that city to help him connect the cities on his Destination Tickets.

The yellow player could claim either the Smyrna-Constantinople or the Smyrna-Palermo route with their station, but they could not use it for both. Additionally, the route needs to have been built by another player so if it's completely unused then they could not.
